# Source layer not recognized in tableFrame element of ArcGIS Pro Layout

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layouts, cartographic-information-model, table-frame

I created a map series layout in ArcGIS Pro, and try to update it from a Python toolbox, using [Cartographic Information Model (CIM)](https://github.com/Esri/cim-spec/blob/main/docs/v3/CIMLayout.md#cimlayout).

Each time the toolbox is running, the layer used to display `tableFrame` in the layout is overwritten. As the link with the `tableFrame` is lost during the process, I loop in layout elements to find my `tableFrame`, get the URI (unique id) of the layer of interest and use it to set the `tableFrame`'s `mapMemberURI`.

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

lyt = aprx.listLayouts('AinsiC_Paysage_Atlas_statsDynamiques_lots_v2')[0]

ms = lyt.mapSeries
mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT', 'Map Frame Series')[0]
mapSeriesLyr = mf.map.listLayers('Reserve_castor')[0]

m = aprx.listMaps("Map2")[0]

lyt_cim = lyt.getDefinition("V2")  # Get the layout's CIM definition

for elm in lyt_cim.elements:
  if elm.name == "Type_subsistance":
      subsi = m.listLayers('Clip_Subsi_Dissolve1')[0]
      subsi_cim = subsi.getDefinition('V2')
      subsi_URI = subsi_cim.uRI
      elm.mapMemberURI = subsi_URI

lyt.setDefinition(lyt_cim)

# Force a refresh of the layout and its associated panes
lyt_cim = lyt.getDefinition('V2')
lyt.setDefinition(lyt_cim)
```

This last step shows no error, but the tableFrame doesn't appear and I can see in the element pane that no layer is selected in the Table parameter.
[image]

I noticed that when I select the table in the interface, and extract the URI from Python script, the URI is *'CIMPATH=map2/clip_subsi_dissolve1.json'*, but when I use the name of the layer to extract the URI, it is *'CIMPATH=map2/clip_subsi_dissolve12.json'*.

What am I missing?